# No warning on implicit conversion

Tags: c++, casting, g++, type-conversion

```
// g++ sizeofint.cpp --std=c++11 -Wconversion -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;
    int a = 0x12345678;
    std::cout << sizeof(int) << "..." << sizeof(uint16_t) << std::endl;
    std::pair<uint16_t, uint16_t> p{a,a}; // !!!! no warning or error on conversion !!!!
    std::cout << p.first << ":" << p.second << std::endl;
    uint16_t b = a; // !!!! correct behavior: -Wconversion triggers warning, which -Werror turns to an error
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

With the above code, you can see clearly a implicit conversion from `int` to `uint16_t` when constructing `p`. However, g++ as of version 4.9.1 does not complain about any conversions when using the parameters provided in the comment at the beginning.

Later, g++ does complain about the implicit conversion to uint16_t when constructing `b`.

I'm trying to make sure that `p`'s construction will result in at least a warning (but preferably an error).

Any thoughts? Is there a flag I don't know about to trigger the correct behavior?

Comment: You hit `std::pair`'s `template<class U, class V> constexpr pair(U&& x, V&& y);` constructor. Since the conversion actually happens inside that constructor (in a system header), you don't get a warning.

Comment: If the construction were inside of a library, I could sort of understand. But as you said, this is in a template... which gets compiled and therefore should be checked.

Comment: @T.C. should it be the answer?

Comment: [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html) : "All warnings, other than those generated by ‘#warning’ (see Diagnostics), are suppressed while GCC is processing a system header." See [your modified example gives you the expected warning](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f227ed0988d1c6ad)

Comment: Is there some way to enable warnings for system headers?

Comment: @Arkadiy, unfortunately not.

Comment: @millsj, thanks that worked. Of course there's tons of other crap now too... just highlights how much behind-the-scenes magic is hacked together. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your code had used the `constexpr pair(const uint16_t& x, const uint16_t& y);` constructor of `std::pair<uint16_t, uint16_t>`, you'd get a warning and/or error. You wouldn't even need `-Wconversion` for this - narrowing conversions inside braces render a program ill-formed.

But instead, overload resolution selected `std::pair`'s `template<class U, class V> constexpr pair(U&& x, V&& y);` constructor, which is a better match. As a result, the conversion happens, not inside the code you wrote, but inside that constructor. Since that constructor is defined in a system header (see [GCC's documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html), hat tip @quantdev), the warning is suppressed by GCC.

While you could use `-Wsystem-headers` to enable warnings from system headers, that option will produce [lots of unrelated warnings](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14dd104aa77be0cf) and so interacts very badly with `-Werror`.