# Why is implicit conversion from pair<int64_t,int64_t> to pair<int,int> allowed?

Tags: c++, c++11, implicit-conversion, std-pair

I've noticed some cases where std::pair will be implicitly converted to a std::pair of a different type without warning, but I can't figure out why. I've had a look through the constructors for std::pair, and can't figure it out. Can somebody explain this to me?

Example:

```
 std::pair<int,int> a = std::pair<int64_t, int64_t>(1,2);
```

Gives no warnings with clang -Wall -Weverything.

Comment: is it duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25535106/no-warning-on-implicit-conversion ?

Comment: Just read the reference http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/operator=/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor

```
template<class U, class V> pair(const pair<U, V>& p);
```

allows copying from any pairs provided the first element of `p` can be converted to first element of pair being constructed, and the same for second elements.